# My internet works extremely slow (ASUS Sabertooth 990FX R2.0)

Tags: networking, internet, asus

I'm completely new to Ubuntu 14.04. A friend installed it on my computer yesterday and we ran into problem that internet runs extremely slow. Sometimes pages time out.

I have installed Window 7 on an SSD. Linux is installed on an HDD (2 partitions).

My computer specs are:

- CPU: AMD FX 8320
- mobo: ASUS Sabertooth 990FX R2.0
- RAM: 8GB
- GPU: Gigabyte HD 5770

In case that we're talking about internet problem, my mobo is using Realtek® 8111F, 1 x Gigabit LAN Controller(s).

Comment: Is the internet slow using Windows?

Comment: No, in windows everything works fine.

Comment: what is the output of `ifconfig -a`

Comment: eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:22:0b:4f:02:58  
          inet addr:192.168.1.64  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ae22:bff:fe4f:258/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:42963 (42.9 KB)  TX bytes:34951 (34.9 KB)
          Interrupt:96 Base address:0xc000

Comment: lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:271 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:271 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:22643 (22.6 KB)  TX bytes:22643 (22.6 KB)

Comment: That looks fine to me. One thing you could try is to change the DNS servers to the google servers -- instructions here 
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it seems that the problem was with the DNS servers. Switching to the google DNS servers (instructions at https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) makes it work better

Comment: How could this help if with the same DNS servers all seems working well on Windows?